# stop div extending below parent

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

I have a div in a div, however the second div does not start right at the top of the parent div, it is shunted down by a header. This second div contains a lot of stuff and will need to scroll, so I set it to 100% height and to allow overflow; however, because it doesn't start right at the top of the parent div, it extends over the bottom of the parent.

Here it is as a code snippet

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;padding:0
}

.profile-box {width: 46.6%; /*max-width: 560px;*/ height: 35%; max-height:600px; background-color:white; margin:1.6%; padding-top: 0.8%; padding-left: 0.8%; padding-right: 0.8%;}
.profile-form {margin-right:5; margin-left:auto; padding-right:3%;}
.profile-slider {width:45%}
.profile-slider-label {margin-right:1%}

.left-align {float:left;}
.right-align {float:right;}
.y-scolling {overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden; height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div class="profile-box right-align" style="background-color:red">
         <h2>Lifestyle</h2>
         <p class="left-align">Scroll for more</p>
         
         <div class="form-horizontal" style="background-color:grey">
             <div class="y-scolling" style="background-color:yellow">
                 <div class="form-group profile-form">
                     <input runat="server" class="profile-slider right-align" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="cat1" />
                     <label class="control-label right-align profile-slider-label" for="cat1">Cat1</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group profile-form">
                     <input runat="server" class="profile-slider right-align" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="cat1" />
                     <label class="control-label right-align profile-slider-label" for="cat1">Cat1</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group profile-form">
                     <input runat="server" class="profile-slider right-align" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="cat1" />
                     <label class="control-label right-align profile-slider-label" for="cat1">Cat1</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group profile-form">
                     <input runat="server" class="profile-slider right-align" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="cat1" />
                     <label class="control-label right-align profile-slider-label" for="cat1">Cat1</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group profile-form">
                     <input runat="server" class="profile-slider right-align" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="cat1" />
                     <label class="control-label right-align profile-slider-label" for="cat1">Cat1</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group profile-form">
                     <input runat="server" class="profile-slider right-align" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="cat1" />
                     <label class="control-label right-align profile-slider-label" for="cat1">Cat1</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group profile-form">
                     <input runat="server" class="profile-slider right-align" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="cat1" />
                     <label class="control-label right-align profile-slider-label" for="cat1">Cat1</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group profile-form">
                     <input runat="server" class="profile-slider right-align" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="cat1" />
                     <label class="control-label right-align profile-slider-label" for="cat1">Cat1</label>
                 </div><div class="form-group profile-form">
                     <input runat="server" class="profile-slider right-align" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="cat1" />
                     <label class="control-label right-align profile-slider-label" for="cat1">Cat1</label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group profile-form">
                     <input runat="server" class="profile-slider right-align" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="cat1" />
                     <label class="control-label right-align profile-slider-label" for="cat1">Cat1</label>
                 </div>
                 
                 <!-- more of these --> 
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image: As you can see, the same height as its container, but just offset.]

[image: More colours in the divs]

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Can you post your css  please. And also note that one of the divs isn't closed properly. Although that is most likely a copy paste error.

Comment: added more info, CSS etc

Answer (score 0):

Try adding overflow: scroll; to the css for that div.

Example:

```
div.someClass { 
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

You can try other overflow properties as well. But from the picture it looks like you want it to scroll within the div. overflow: hidden may be an option as well.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, but maybe he already tried this. I'm waiting for him to post his CSS.

Comment: yea he mentions the overflow property but I don't know if he tried scroll or not

Comment: Or `overflow: auto` so that `x` & `y` scrollbar tracks are only visible when needed.

Comment: added more info, CSS etc